# Control Drop Down Appearance

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently we have drop down that people can add project names to.  When people add a long project name it widens the drop down and throws off the layout of the page.

I would like to be able to control the width of the drop down list on the web form, but display wider if needed when a user clicks on it so they can read the complete name.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the width within your markup(this will keep it from breaking the page), having it display wider works automatically in some browsers(chrome/firefox), but others it does not work (IE 6 ,7).  So if the text is larger than the drop down, the drop down section will grow bigger but not break your page.

I had a set amount of characters that a user can type in, and I made the font kind of small, for IE users.